Employee always seems distracted affecting others and his work, found out finally what it is, wondering if I can say something
As a background this is a company working on logistics software, we also work from home.
Have an employee that for the past 2-3 months started making a lot of mistakes.  Constantly seems distracted and its really getting on my nerves cause I end up finding the mistakes (bugs) or the inconsistencies (ux) in the work.
Well one day we were on a conference call and reviewing some code and all of a sudden random "blafhsfhsfghashgfsahhgf" typing comes in, and I asked what are you doing?  It kept happening and come to find out its a cat that keeps typing on his keyboard.  I asked if he could please remove the cat from the room as we have a deadline and around 5 minutes later it happened again.
The employee mentioned if he removes the cat and closes the door the cat starts screaming.  Sorry I'm not really a cat person nor do I really want to be.  I am however tired of dealing with this as it is impacting others, timing, and myself.
Can I bring up this topic with this employee?

A cat wouldn’t cause problems with code that can compile or UI design issues they might walk on the keyboard but that’s an easy problem to solve. So what’s your question? You have no power over them and their choices to have or not have a cat as a pet. I will keep my other thoughts to myself.

The book "Becoming a Technical Leader" by Gerald M. Weinberg has a short chapter about an employee who seemed very distracted and whose work quality fell. Definitely worth reading.

@HappyIdiot - thank you, I love reading so will check this out!

There is no way you can "know" that having a cat has caused all these mistakes and distractions. More importantly, you don't need to.
When someone who reports to you starts to do poorly, it is perfectly fine to tell them so. (If they don't report to you, it may not be.) Generally, starting with "you have been making so many mistakes the last 2 or 3 months" is not the way to do that. You react to the mistakes, you connect them to the business (the release was delayed; I had to work on the weekend to fix this to avoid a delay; we had to pay money; whatever.) Sometimes you might say "this seems like the same sort of mistake as a month ago, you started before you got the sample file and then had to backtrack" or "this seems like a consistent problem for you".
It's nice to offer help, like different equipment, training, a process change where someone looks things over before they go live -- the exact help depends on the problem -- if there is something you can offer. If you're the boss, and these mistakes are threatening the person's continued employment, it's ok to tell them that too. It is possible that you can't guess what help they need or how to fix the problem. You don't have to. It's only fair to let them know they aren't doing well enough. If you like them and want to keep them, it's nice to work towards that, too.
What is not ok is "I decided your problem is you have a cat and I insist you get rid of it or train it to not mind being locked out of your office." Even if the person told you the cat is why they aren't performing well lately, the actual cat-related solution is none of your business. But that hasn't happened here. There was just a temporary issue that a cat walked on a keyboard once and you've decided that explains everything. I very much doubt that it does.
If you're not this person's manager, and the mistakes truly are causing you issues, take those issues to your manager. But do not mention the cat. The cat is not the point.

I am his manager, and I understand what you are saying I would of course not approach it like "You keep making mistakes and its all due to your furball".  What I am trying to say is I have witnessed it over and over to be cat related.  Other employees who work with my employee have also stated that this employee is always being distracted by his cats (either via camera teams) or via the employee making a remark about how his cat is bugging him.  What I dont understand (and again excuse me I am not a cat person) why isnt the cat taken out of the room?

you don't need to understand it. You just need to focus on the work issue: distraction, mistakes, poor performance. Sorting out the cat issue is not your problem and it's an over-reach. Look, maybe there used to be a romantic partner in the home who entertained the cat: would you tell this employee to get out there and find a new partner? I sincerely hope not, because it's none of your business who they live with. That extends to the cat too. The mistakes are what you talk about. Because we all get distracted sometimes but we don't check in our mistakes afterwards, we fix them.

Right and I think I have gone and talked to this employee about us missing goals and about us making other departments look bad based on these issues too many times now.  I will have to let this person know that yes in fact this will cause him to lose his job, he will have to figure out the cat situation.

@JonH From a different perspective it may actually be more of a distraction if the cat is locked out of the room.  Some cats object to locked doors and will scratch at them in order get to the other side.  The noise of a cat doing this is very distracting.

@PeterM - still I think either way he needs to make a choice, be jobless and have cats surrounding him.  Or keep his job and pay for new doors.  Sorry life is tough ultimately I have people to report to too.

@JonH - If you are missing goals, are those goals perhaps not realistic, with the team you have? That falls on you as a manager not the employee with the cat.

@Donald Ill answer that with no.

Lots of people have cats and manage to work just fine. I will sometimes have my cat sit on my lap as I'm on a video call, and sometimes the cat gives me a kiss on camera; that's not a problem. I'll very occasionally need to drop a comment into the chat of "I'm still listening, just getting up for a sec to let the cat into the room" if he's meowing — but it's like, a 5-second distraction, and then I'm back. It certainly does not affect the overall quality of my deliverables. I strongly suspect that you have incorrectly identified the root cause of the problem.

@JonH You started off by explaining the situation calmly and rationally but thinking about this has caused you to become increasingly upset, and now you have literally said "...he needs to make a choice, be jobless and have cats surrounding him. Or keep his job...". Those were your exact words. Doesn't that strike you in a sense of, in a professional position, as a manager, you could be reacting to this in a slightly better way?

If a manager gave me an ultimatum about my pet, I would disable my camera and mute my microphone, and then effectively lie about the pet or just go directly to HR and demand a different manager. It’s a ridiculous ask as a manager, my pet as an employee, doesn’t effect my work productivity.

@Donald I would be looking for a new job literally that evening before dinner. Which I guess, to be fair, is one of OP's proposed solutions.

I would be looking for a new manager. Maybe within the same company, but this would give me severe doubts about my current manager's judgment. And makes me wonder just how overstressed JonH is, and what other mistakes he is making.

@keshlam - mistakes?  You're going off topic.  The true mistake is letting this go on for too long, that is my biggest mistake.

@JonH: That isn't, however, the question you asked us to respond to.

@jonh: But, yes, it is the question you should be addressing. Blaming the cat is a mistake. Focus on managing your employee, and let the employee decide whether they need to manage the cat. You are not the cat's manager, you are the cat's second-line.

You are jumping to conclusions and focusing on the wrong thing.
The cat is not the core problem, and is almost certainly not the cause of anything but that one bit of keyboard noise.
It's legitimate to ask that the employee keep the cat from significantly interrupting teleconferences. One instance of cat typing is not significant interruption, nor does it say anything about the employee's general work habits.
If there are things the employee needs to improve, tell them what they need to improve. How they achieve it is up to them, unless they ask you for advice. And advising them to exclude the cat is going to come across as petty, at best.
People have pets, and kids. People who work remotely are sometimes interrupted by their pets, or kids. Most folks handle those interruptions just fine. Most folks who attend teleconferences understand this, and are more amused than annoyed when it happens, as long as it does not prevent work from being done.
If the employee is underperforming, focus on what they need to improve. The cat, if you will excuse the mixed metaphor, is almost certainly a red herring.

What you might do, if cat typing becomes common, is suggest to the employee that having a cat tree in the office (or even a cushion of the desk) so the cat has it's own dedicated place to observe from may decrease how much time the cat spends actively requesting attention. Also, it is sometimes possible to negotiate with a cat that they can sit in your lap as long as they stay low enough not to interfere with typing; that takes some patience and training and a cooperative cat.  But you are still micromanaging the wrong problem.

Right its not only typing, its the attention of the animal, the fact that it jumps on him, the fact that it makes noises and bugs him.  He needs a better solution, unfortunately I nor my team cannot tolerate it anymore.  Nor can we we help him escort his cat.  He has a decision to make, figure out how to work and concentrate without the cat bugging him and us or lose his job.

@JonH It seems like you've already made up your mind on this issue.

The fact that the cat jumps on him and asks for attention has nothing to do with the rest of you. If it bothers you, that is your problem, not his. The only thing that you can legitimately complain about is if his work product is not up to requirements. Excluding the cat from his workplace is unlikely to have useful effect, and frankly the suggestion says a lot more about your lack of tolerance than his lack of focus.

The phrase"not even wrong" comes to mind.


Can I bring up this topic with this employee?

Assuming you are this employee's manager, you can and you must bring up this topic.
If the employee is making a lot of mistakes that result in bugs and inconsistencies, then these are what you must address and get corrected. This is the only topic.
It's not important if this is due to a cat, lack of concentration, or not enough checking of his work. The cat is his problem - don't make it yours.
Talk about the quality of the work. Talk about seeming distracted. Don't talk about the cat.

If the employee is unable or unwilling to fix his arrangements so that he can produce the work you're paying him for then he has ceased to be an asset and needs to be moved on.
I wouldn't make it a cat issue, I'd make it a performance issue because it makes no difference if it's a cat, dog, or his kids. He needs to make sure it doesn't persistently impact on his work, just like everyone else.
I have 6 kids and a cat. They can and do interrupt my work sometimes, but it's rare and makes zero difference to my output.
